# Python tkinter - GUI is 'lagging' even with Multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am writing a tkinter project where I have a serial connection to an instrument.
Once the connection is established (accomplished by clicking on a push button on the GUI), I am running a loop in which I ask the instruments all sorts of question and write the answers in a log (.txt).

I call the loop in the following manner:

```
def Polling():
   global after_polling
   Loop()
   after_polling = app.after(10, func = Polling)
```

During the loop, I need to wait for a X amount of ms, so I do the following:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=sleepms(val))
t.start()
t.join()
```

I need to wait until the X amount of time has passed, hence the line `t.join()`

The `sleepms` function is:

```
def sleepms(time_ms):
   time_s=time_ms/1000
   time.sleep(time_s)
```

So I am not sure why the GUI becomes very unresponsive (or takes wayyy to much time to respond).

Anyone has any idea what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: `t = threading.Thread(target=sleepms(val))` should be `t = threading.Thread(target=sleepms, args=(val,))`.  But running only `sleep()` in a thread is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Using threads is not like you did:

```py
t = threading.Thread(target=sleepms(val))
t.start()
t.join()
```

That's because you have spawn a thread but in the meanwhile the main program is blocked waiting `t.join`: the program is still working in a sequential way, not in parallel.

What you normally do with threads is something like that:

```py
t = threading.Thread(target=sleepms(val))
t.start()
# do something here
t.join()
```

In your case one option is not to join the tread, keep it alive and pass information to it to do the job.
Simple example at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-thread-in-tkinter-python/

Do something like that:

1. Write the core code in a separate function (I.E. connect to the instrument, wait, write log..., everything that you need). You can test the software without the GUI, just using the shell.
2. Add the GUI and on the keypress event of tkinter spawn the other thread with your core code.
3. Pay attention no to spawn a thread at every keypress, for example use a flag to check if the thread is already up.
4. If you need something to display something in your GUI after that the thread has performed what it should, you can use some shared data structure.
   Pay attention because using threads you can have concurrency problems (both the main thread and secondary thread can modify the same shared variables), but in general if the secondary threads writes in a shared variable and the main thread only reads you should be able to do in a simple way.
   This is just to make it simple because there are better alternatives to share data between thread.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What would you suggest to do if I only need my thread to wait X time? (basically, halt the the Loop() function, but still keep the GUI responsive)